# Cygwin: Up Key only displays the last command programmatically added in bash history

Tags: bash, cygwin, history

The file .bash_history in my cygwin user folder contains a lot of commands. In my .bashrc file I have added one line for sourcing my script

```
source myScript.sh
```

Case #1. myScript.sh looks like this:

```
echo "This is a test application."
```

When I run cygwin, the echo message is displayed. If I press the Up Key, I can scroll through all commands from history.

Case #2. myScript.sh looks like this:

```
echo "This is a test application."
history -s "This is history test command"
```

When I run cygwin, the echo message is displayed. But now if I press the Up Key, I can only find the "This is history test command" command.

Can someone please explain me what am I doing wrong? in myScript.sh I need to prepare a command for the user based on some variables, a command the user can simply find it and execute it by pressing Up Key and hitting enter when the prompt appears.

Comment: no problem for me, the history is all there. How are you running the script ?

Comment: I start Cygwin by running Cygwin.bat in the root of cygwin64 folder. This will load the .bashrc file which will source myScript.sh